# GNU Make: why call function can't be used on simply expanded variables? $1 is not expanded

Tags: variables, call, gnu-make

example:

```
define a :=                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
abc := $$1
endef 

$(eval $(call a,b))
```

the variable `abc` is not `b`. In my knowledge, value of `a` is `abc := $1`, then call will exapnd to `abc := b`

Why call function can't be used on simply expanded variable, this is not mentioned in the GNU Make manual.

Comment: @MadScientist Could you help me? thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a variable is expanded via simple expansion, it's never expanded again.  That's the whole point of `:=`.  So when the variable is defined initially it is set to the static string `abc := $1`.  Once that's done, it doesn't matter how many different times it appears in an expanded context: it won't actually change again.